# Can we skip instantiation of test class inside factory method in TestNG?

Tags: java, testing, testng

So my class structure is as follows:
(Note that I am using **TestNG** framework.)

```java
public class A {
    @Factory 
    public Object[] tst_createFactoryTests() {
        // Creates test classes if NUM is positive
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    private static final int NUM = 10;
}

public class C extends A {
    private static final int NUM = 20;
}

public class D extends A {
    private static final int NUM = -30;
}
```

- So, basically we have a super class A. And classes B, C, & D extend class A.
- Every time when class A is invoked by one of it's subclass, it is supposed to create a test for the class which invokes it if the value of NUM is positive
- For example, in case of class B and class C, since the value of NUM is positive, the factory method in class A should create test for them (one for class B and one for class C).
- On the other hand, in case of class D, since the value of NUM is negative (-30), the factory method in class A should skip test instantiation for class D.
- I tried to implement it with a simple if-else logic, but I am getting following error:

`An error occurred while instantiating class A. Check to make sure it can be instantiated. Root cause: The Factory method A.tst_createFactoryTests() should have produced at-least one instance`

- So, my question is do we have a way by which we can skip instantiation of a factory method based on a condition for some of the sub-classes which invoke it? Let me know if I need to provide any more context to it. Note that I am using **TestNG** framework.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Factory methods are expected to produce testclass (A class which has
> one or more `@Test` methods is called a test class) instances.

Factory methods are invoked via two mechanisms:

1. Annotating a parameterised constructor (this is usually coupled with a data provider so that one can create multiple test class instances) with a `@Factory` annotation.
2. Creating a static method of the form `public static Object[] myMethod()` and having it annotated with the `@Factory` annotation.

In both the cases, TestNG would end up invoking the factory method all the time and it can't be done selectively.

```
Test class is a regular class which houses one or more `@Test` annotated test methods.
```

So you are expecting that we build some condition (based on positivity of a number that gets yielded by every test class) based on which the factory method returns or does not return the test class instance.

Here's where the confusion starts:

- If the field is an instance level field, then the factory method would not be able to access the field until the object gets instantiated and that is what we are conditionally trying to control.
- If the field is a static field, then you would need to use reflection to check the value of that field (if you would like it to be generic) and then proceed with instantiation, which in my opinion is kind of over engineering.

So in short, there's no built in way in which you can have a selective execution of a Factory method.